# ASH: IN_PARSE and IN_SQL_EXECUTION simultaneously?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can someone please point me towards documentation on the V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY columns IN_PARSE, IN_HARD_PARSE and IN_SQL_EXECUTION?

Version is 11.2.0.3

I have a TMPDLT-Query of an aggregate-mview fast-refresh (http://www.oaktable.net/content/fast-refresh-aggregate-only-materialized-views-%E2%80%93-introduction) that stalls other queries via a library cache lock for over 20 minutes 2 out of 7 days.

My question is: This TMPDLT-Query in ASH shows as IN_PARSE, IN_HARD_PARSE and IN_SQL_EXECUTION **simultaneously** for 20 minutes. According to SQL_PLAN_OPERATION and SQL_PLAN_OPTIONS it is doing a TABLE ACCESS FULL on the one MLOG-table it needs and according to file# it is in the UNDO table space.

My question: Have you ever seen sessions in ASH being IN_PARSE, IN_HARD_PARSE and IN_SQL_EXECUTION simultaneously? For 20 minutes? Is this normal? What does it mean? How can it full table scan already and still be in hard parse? Is this maybe related to the result_cache hint in the query? Or an effect of dynamic sampling?

Many thanks!

**Update for BobC:**

Plan of the query at the time the problem happened:

[image]

OTHER_XML as not fully shown above:

```
<other_xml>
<info type="db_version">11.2.0.3</info>
<info type="parse_schema">
    <![CDATA["SYS"]]>
</info>
<info type="plan_hash">2866394291</info>
<info type="plan_hash_2">1823969956</info>
<outline_data>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('11.2.0.3')]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[DB_VERSION('11.2.0.3')]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$335DD26A")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[MERGE(@"SEL$3")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$ABDE6DFF")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[MERGE(@"SEL$6")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$4")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE(@"SEL$5")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[OUTLINE(@"SEL$6")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$4" "V4"@"SEL$4")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$ABDE6DFF" "DLT$"@"SEL$6")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$1" "MAS$"@"SEL$1")]]>
    </hint>
    <hint>
        <![CDATA[FULL(@"SEL$335DD26A" "MAS$"@"SEL$3")]]>
    </hint>
</outline_data>
```

SQL of the query (anonymized a bit):

```
WITH "TMPDLT$_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" AS(
    SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE(LIFETIME=SESSION) */
        "MAS$"."RID$"        "RID$",
        "MAS$"."PARTITION_YYYY",
        "MAS$"."ZZZZZZZZZ",
        "MAS$"."KEY",
        "MAS$"."VALUE",
        decode("MAS$"."OLD_NEW$$",'N','I','D')"DML$$",
        "MAS$"."OLD_NEW$$"   "OLD_NEW$$",
        "MAS$"."TIME$$"      "TIME$$",
        "MAS$"."DMLTYPE$$"   "DMLTYPE$$"
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                "MAS$".*,
                MIN("MAS$"."SEQ$$")OVER(
                    PARTITION BY "MAS$"."RID$"
                )"MINSEQ$$",
                MAX("MAS$"."SEQ$$")OVER(
                    PARTITION BY "MAS$"."RID$"
                )"MAXSEQ$$"
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT  /*+ CARDINALITY(MAS$ 0) */
                        chartorowid("MAS$"."M_ROW$$")rid$,
                        "MAS$"."PARTITION_YYYY",
                        "MAS$"."ZZZZZZZZZ",
                        "MAS$"."KEY",
                        "MAS$"."VALUE",
                        decode("MAS$".old_new$$,'N','I','D')dml$$,
                        "MAS$"."DMLTYPE$$"    "DMLTYPE$$",
                        "MAS$"."SEQUENCE$$"   "SEQ$$",
                        "MAS$"."OLD_NEW$$"    "OLD_NEW$$",
                        "MAS$"."SNAPTIME$$"   "TIME$$"
                    FROM
                        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"."MLOG$_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "MAS$"
                    WHERE
                        "MAS$".snaptime$$ > :b_st0
                )AS OF SNAPSHOT(:b_scn)"MAS$"
        )"MAS$"
    WHERE
        ((("MAS$"."OLD_NEW$$" = 'N')
          AND("MAS$"."SEQ$$" = "MAS$"."MAXSEQ$$"))
         OR(("MAS$"."OLD_NEW$$" IN(
            'O',
            'U'
        ))
            AND("MAS$"."SEQ$$" = "MAS$"."MINSEQ$$")))
)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ddt_1 = 'D'
             AND ddt_2 = 'I' THEN
            'U'
        ELSE
            ddt_1
    END "DML$$",
    MAX(mtime)"TIME$$"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(dd_type)OVER(
                PARTITION BY rid,old_new
            )ddt_1,
            MAX(dd_type)OVER(
                PARTITION BY rid,old_new
            )ddt_2,
            mtime
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    "DLT$"."RID$"     rid,
                    "DLT$"."DML$$"    dd_type,
                    "DLT$"."TIME$$"   mtime,
                    CASE
                        WHEN "DLT$"."DMLTYPE$$" = 'U'
                             AND "DLT$"."OLD_NEW$$" = 'N' THEN
                            'U'
                        ELSE
                            "DLT$"."OLD_NEW$$"
                    END old_new
                FROM
                    "TMPDLT$_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "DLT$"
            )v3
    )v4
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN ddt_1 = 'D'
             AND ddt_2 = 'I' THEN
            'U'
        ELSE
            ddt_1
    END
```

Comment: Have I seen this? Yes. Is it normal? No. It's possible to have this situation with certain execution plans. Can you post the SQL Monitor (ideally) or Explain Plan of the offending query

Comment: @BobC thank you - please see above